# write in the android calendar

Tags: android, calendar

As part of a project, I created an android application which communicates with an online database (MySQL) to integrate the appointment has taken the online calendar.
I collect the data, converted to Json, but when the inscrires in the agenda of android mobile I encounter a probleme, here is my code : (sorry for my english )

EDIT :

```
public class calendrier extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
                        new String[] { "_id", "displayName" }, "selected=1",
                        null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String[] calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            int[] calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < calNames.length; i++) {

                calIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
                calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            if (calIds.length > 0) {
                // we're safe here to do any further work
            }

            // grab calendar id from above
            int cal_id = calIds[0];

            // set the content value
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put("calendar_id", cal_id);
            cv.put("title", "titre");
            cv.put("description", "bla bla bla");
            cv.put("eventLocation", "city");
            // note: you're going to need to convert the desired date into
            // milliseconds
            cv.put("dtstart", System.currentTimeMillis());
            cv.put("dtend", System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
            cv.put("allDay", 0); // true = 1, false = 0
            cv.put("hasAlarm", 1);

            // once desired fields are set, insert it into the table
            getContentResolver().insert(
                    Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), cv);
        }
    }
}
```

this code works but it asks me if I want to participate in the event when I open it and I wish he does not do

thanks

Answer (score 0):

//did U include permission in your manifest.xml file

```
android.permission.READ_CALENDAR
android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR

String  WRITE_CALENDAR  Allows an application to write (but not read) the user's calendar data.
```

Comment: Yes i include this 

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>

Answer (score 0):

The Uri of Calendar has changed from Android 2.2 .

```
Old (2.1 and before): content://calendar/
New (2.2): content://com.android.calendar/
```

Change your Uri to the new one.

There is no Calendar Application by default in Android. So the Uri may not work at all.
 If, you are getting the first error message as "Failed to find provider info for com.android.calendar", you need to check the handset you are using to debug uses which Calendar URI. 
To insert Time in Calendar event, you can use the following code example:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    cv.put("dtstart", ""+calendar.getTimeInMillis());  
    cv.put("dtend", ""+calendar.getTimeInMillis()+10000);
```

Comment: thanks but unknow URL content://com.android.calendar/   :( :(

Comment: thanks for your response , android 2.3 need use : content://com.android.calendar/calendars
 but i have new errors :03-06 09:47:01.477 E/AndroidRuntime(17876): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException :

Comment: Thanks Akhil but when i add to my code : 

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.getTimeInMillis();
event.put("dtstart", ""+calendar.getTimeInMillis());  
event.put("dtend", ""+calendar.getTimeInMillis()+10000);

i have  java.lang.NullPointerException 

I edited my first post to show you the logcat